# What is this use of commas called?

Tags: punctuation

In this sentence:

> Travel blogger, Marina Piro, left her job in 2016 and decided to hit the road with her best canine friend, Odie.

Is there a special name for the usage of the first two commas, and are they even necessary? I find them extremely jarring and unnecessary but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I also find it jarring, and likely unnecessary.

Comment: It's often called "commatosis".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the original quote does not have commas around the name.

Comment: @Cascabel it's not just about this particular quote. I see this used all the time.

Comment: When you see that kind of use, they're called "parenthetical commas."  http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct:

> Travel blogger Marina Piro left her job in 2016.

This is also correct:

> A/the travel blogger, Marina Piro, left her job in 2016.

In the second case, the thing between the commas is called an *appositive*. An appositive simply repeats and renames the thing that it follows. It could be removed, and the sentence would still make sense.

Comment: could you edit your answer to also mention that these are called parenthetical commas?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.lonelyplanet.com/news/2017/01/18/woman-quit-job-renovated-van-order-travel-dog/

The above link is the original, which does not have commas around Marina Piro.  The commas are incorrect, as they make her name non-restrictive; if the commas were correct, *travel blogger* would need a determiner.

Comment: This is where I read it: http://cheezburger.com/2109189/this-woman-is-travelling-the-world-with-her-dog-in-a-special-customized-van

Comment: @voodoo-burger That particular quote has at least 3 errors in it ranging from mis-placed commas to a comma splice and even a mis-matched determiner.